# invalid length of startup packet when trying to connect to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, networking

My Postgres runs on docker, here is the docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_dev
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-mypassword}
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
       - postgres-dnb-dev:/data/postgres
    ports:
            - "127.0.0.1:5432:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
    postgres-dnb-dev:
```

I use Haproxy to define DNS, my DNS is dev.haproxy.local

When i try to connect to this DNS from my browser(another pc on the same network) i got 502 bad gateway and see in the docker container of postgres log:

```
PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

2023-02-15 10:10:45.162 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.2 (Debian 15.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2023-02-15 10:10:45.162 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-02-15 10:10:45.162 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-02-15 10:10:45.164 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-02-15 10:10:45.166 UTC [29] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-02-15 10:10:39 UTC
2023-02-15 10:10:45.169 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections


2023-02-15 10:11:05.175 UTC [33] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2023-02-15 10:11:05.243 UTC [34] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
```

It was working the day before, nothing changed on the network.
Does anyone know what is the solution can be?
thanks.